# html_options return double value

Tags: smarty

I want to select multiple options in smarty by using html_options. here is my code:

```
<?php
    $sql_i = "SELECT id FROM ".$GLOBALS['table']['property']." WHERE  featured = 'Y' ORDER BY `id` DESC";
    $res_i= $GLOBALS['db']->sql_query($sql_i);
    $smarty->assign('featured_name', $GLOBALS['db']->sql_fetchrowset($res_i));

    $sql_p = "SELECT pname FROM ".$GLOBALS['table']['property']." WHERE  featured = 'Y' ORDER BY `id` DESC";
    $res_p = $GLOBALS['db']->sql_query($sql_p);
    $smarty->assign('featured_id', $GLOBALS['db']->sql_fetchrowset($res_p));
?>

<select name="property_id">
<option value="">---Select--</option>
{html_options values=$featured_id output=$featured_name selected=$featured_id}
</select>
```

Output:

```
<select name="property_id">
<option value="">---Select--</option>
<optgroup label="Array">
<option label="Plaza del Sol" value="0">Plaza del Sol</option>
<option label="Plaza del Sol" value="pname">Plaza del Sol</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Array">
<option label="Plaza Del Sol" value="0">Plaza Del Sol</option>
<option label="Plaza Del Sol" value="pname">Plaza Del Sol</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Array">
<option label="Park Terrace " value="0">Park Terrace </option>
<option label="Park Terrace " value="pname">Park Terrace </option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Array">
<option label="Park Terrace 1" value="0">Park Terrace 1</option>
<option label="Park Terrace 1" value="pname">Park Terrace 1</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Array">
<option label="test" value="0">test</option>
<option label="test" value="pname">test</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

how to solve this problem???

Comment: $featured_id = 115, 114 are actually id and $featured_name = somthing1, something2.look at the output section "option value" didn't get any value. it return "0" and "id"(where id don't get value). and "output" returns $featured_id. all are double

Comment: take off selected=$featured_id and show us what that renders

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `sql_fetchrowset()` is not returning a single dimension array, which you need for those attributes to have a simple dropdown. I'm going to take a stab in the dark here, try this:

```
<?php
// You don't need two identical queries
    $query = "SELECT pname,id FROM ".$GLOBALS['table']['property']." WHERE featured = 'Y' ORDER BY `id` DESC";
    $result = $GLOBALS['db']->sql_query($query);
    $featured_id = '';
    foreach ($GLOBALS['db']->sql_fetchrowset($result) as $row):

        // Assuming $row is an object, use appropriate syntax otherwise
        $options[$row->id] = $row->pname;

        // If you know what the featured id is, use this
        // if ($row->id == $my_featured_id):

// Or maybe featured_id is INT(1) OR BOOLEAN value in your table?
// Make sure to SELECT it if this is the case
// Also make sure you handle the possibility of two featured ids in one loop
        if ($row->featured_id == 1):

            $featured_id = $row->id;

        endif;

    endforeach;
    $smarty->assign('options', $options);
    $smarty->assign('featured_id', $featured_id);
?>

<select name="property_id">
<option value="">---Select--</option>
{html_options options=$options selected=$featured_id}
</select>
```

You don't need to use `values` and `output` in [Smarty {htmloptions}](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.html.options.tpl), `options` with an associative array will do. You're probably passing an array of arrays to each attribute.